# Removing more than 1 item in listbox

Tags: c#, listboxitems

please help me how can remove more than 1 item in a `listbox`.I know the code for removing 1 item: `listbox.Items.RemoveAt(i)`
but for more than 1 item selected in a listbox,what is the code? write the code for example in button-click event.I have only a button and a listbox in my winform.(write codes in C#)

Comment: just loop trough the selected item and remove them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
while(listbox.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
 {
    listbox.Items.Remove(listbox.SelectedItem);
 }
```

Comment: nice start on SO bro :)

Answer (score 0):

```
ListBox1.ClearSelection();

    //or

    foreach (ListItem listItem in ListBox1.Items)
    {
        listItem.Selected = false;
    }


     List<ListItem> itemsToRemove = new List<ListItem>();
    foreach (ListItem listItem in ListBox1.Items)
    {
        if (listItem.Selected)
            itemsToRemove.Add(listItem);
    }

    foreach (ListItem listItem in itemsToRemove)
    {
        ListBox1.Items.Remove(listItem);
    }
```

Comment: Right idea but am wondering what is `ListItem` and `listItem.Selected`?